# CUDA multiple multiplication of the matrix in the kernel code

Tags: c++, cuda, matrix-multiplication

Function for matrix multiplication:

```
__global__ void gpu_matrix_mult(float *a, float *b, float *c, int m, int n, int k)
{
    int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    float sum = 0;
    if (col < k && row < m)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            sum += a[row * n + i] * b[i * k + col];
        }
        c[row * k + col] = sum;
    }
}
```

Then the function is invoked in the following loop:

```
int currentActivityCount = -1;

while (activityCount != currentActivityCount)
{
    if (currentActivityCount > -1)
    {
        cudaMemcpy(d_b, h_b_new, sizeof(int)*m*k, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    }

    gpu_matrix_mult << <dimGrid, dimBlock >> >(d_a, d_b, d_c, m, n, k);

    cudaMemcpy(h_c, d_c, sizeof(int)*m*k, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    currentActivityCount = activityCount;
    activityCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < k; ++j)
        {
            if (h_c[i*k + j] >= 0.5)
            {
                activityCount++;

                h_b_new[i * k + j] = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                h_b_new[i * k + j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    during++;
    printf("Count of activity: %d During: %d\n", activityCount, during);
}
```

My target is move this loop into "gpu_matrix_mult" function so that the transfer of data between GPU occurs only two times it means before and after invoked function, instead in every  iteration of loop. I have been trying some ways, but none worked. Is that solution is possible?

Comment: The `while` loop doesn't have to be on the gpu. You should focus on moving the code that counts the activity to the gpu. You can do that with a simple reduction kernel. Once you have that on the GPU you don't actually need the `cudaMemcopy` of the whole arrays on every iteration. just the `activityCount` result from the gpu to the cpu and that's it.

Comment: Also, you could optimize the `gpu_matrix_mul` using shared memory.

Comment: I dont think it is quite possible to do this using only the GPU, because you need to globally synchronise all the thread blocks for this to work. I suggest that you optimise the memory transfers with Paged memory.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something in the kernel like this:

```
__device__ int activityCount;
__global__ void gpu_matrix_mult(float *a, float *b0, float *b1, float *c, int m, int n, int k)
{
    int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    float sum = 0;
    if (col < k && row < m)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            sum += a[row * n + i] * b0[i * k + col];
        }
        c[row * k + col] = sum;
        if (sum >= 0.5)
        {
            atomicAdd(&activityCount, 1);
            b1[i * k + j] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            b1[i * k + j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

// .............


int currentActivityCount = -1;
int activityCount_h = 0;
while (activityCount_h != currentActivityCount)
{
    if (currentActivityCount > -1)
    {
        float *tmp = d_b0;
        d_b0 = d_b1;
        d_b1 = tmp;
    }
    currentActivityCount = activityCount_h;
    activityCount_h = 0;
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(activityCount, &activityCount_h, sizeof(int));
    gpu_matrix_mult<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(d_a, d_b0, d_b1, d_c, m, n, k);
    cudaMemcpyfromSymbol(&activityCount_h, activity, sizeof(int));

    during++;
    printf("Count of activity: %d During: %d\n", activityCount, during);
}
```

[Obviously never compiled or run, use at own risk]

i.e. the inner loops for calculating `activityCount` can be run within the kernel on the device after the matrix multiply. This requires two `b` matrices in memory on the GPU, but there is only pointer swapping required on the host to update them, which is basically zero cost. The memory transfers are reduce to a single integer twice per outer loop iteration, which will be rather fast.